# Как Android определяет из какого файла нужно достать строку в зависимости от локали?

Tags: android, android-sdk

Проблема такая, в приложении есть экран со сменой языка на нем списком языков и кнопка сохранить, нужно чтобы при нажатии на язык надпись на кнопке менялась в соответствии с локалью выбранного языка. Например выбрали English на кнопке надпись должна поменяться, вместо "сохранить" должно быть "save". Вопрос в том как андроид определяет к какому файлу со строками обратиться и как этот момент перехватить и переопределить чтобы менять локаль строки

**РЕШЕНИЕ**

```
val context = LocalContext.current
val conf = context.resources.configuration`conf.setLocale(Locale1(locale ?: "ru"))
val resources = context.createConfigurationContext(conf)
val textRes = R.string.your_string
    localizedString.value = resources.getString(textRes)`
```

метод createConfigurationContext нужно использовать вместо устаревшего конструктора класса Resources, метод создает новый контекст с новой конфигурацей который не является общим (не поменяет язык во всем приложении) подробнее: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#createConfigurationContext(android.content.res.Configuration)

Comment: Опубликуйте решение как ответ. Так будет логичнее, нагляднее, вы сможете отметить ответ как решение и повысить себе репутацию.

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Main extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String languageToLoad  = "fa"; // код языка, который вы хотите сделать
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad); 
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
      getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }
}
```

Подробнее здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-app-language-programmatically-in-android

Comment: это не совсем то, мне не нужно чтобы локаль поменялась везде, нужно только для конкретной строки, но все равно спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Если для одной конкретной строки то можно так: `Configuration conf = getResources().getConfiguration();
conf.locale = new Locale("pl");
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
Resources resources = new Resources(getAssets(), metrics, conf);
String str = resources.getString(id);`

Comment: Попробовал, строка конечно меняется, но к сожалению меняется язык везде

Comment: Наверное надо сделать копию объекта `Configuration` и на копии менять локаль и создавать `Resources`